# android google Drive open file intent

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Asking user to select a file from drive account using

```
           IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi   .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
            .build(getGoogleApiClient());
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }
```

2. How can I set a starting default folder, like say I want open a folder created by my app by default when the drive file explorer opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setActivityStartFolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html#setActivityStartFolder(com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId)) in the OpenFileActivityBuilder and specify the DriveId for your folder.